# how do i change Grid.RowDefinitions with Uid="Row6" it's min and max Height when certain form is open calling this Grid with it during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Let say i declare a form with a grid design which is use or re-called in other form when opened. it's xaml id is like this:

```
    <Grid x:Uid="SplittingGrid" x:Name="SplittingGrid" Grid.Row="2" Background="Gray" Height="auto">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition x:Uid="Row5" Height="200*" />
                    <RowDefinition x:Uid="Row6" Height="120*" MaxHeight="250" MinHeight="150" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   </Grid>
```

this is just how i show the code for now but what if i wanted to change it's Max and Min height on a Certain form initiated this xaml how can i do that during run time.

```
public void InitGridForm()
        {               

            if (GlobalVar.SETnewFORMS_OPEN == 1)
            {
                PartsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                Row6 Set Max and Min Size.
            }
            else
            {
                PartsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;    
            }       
        }
```

this is the code i set on the form of the grid when it is initialize i set a condition that if a certain form is opened this is it's settings and if a certain form is opened and called this gridform this is his settings.

my question is how do i set dynamically the max and min size of the grid in runtime? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I did understand you problem, but I hope so.
If you change the `x:Uid="Row6"` to `x:Name="Row6"` in your xaml, you can just set these both properties like this in the code behind:

```
if (GlobalVar.SETnewFORMS_OPEN == 1)
{
    PartsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    this.Row6.MinHeight = 400;
    this.Row6.MaxHeight = 600;
}
else
{
    PartsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```